# Map some input value to a custom type

Tags: scala

Imagine I have some type `MyType`, that is a union, like:

```
MyType.StringValue("a string")
MyType.LongValue(100L)
MyType.DoubleValue(200.09)
```

I need to map values of some type `T` to `MyType`.

What I want to *avoid* is a very long pattern match like:

```
def convert(x: Any) = x match {
  case x: Long => MyType.LongValue(x)
  ...
  ...
}
```

What options are available to me? I have heard/seen some stuff about traits and implicits. I'm curious if anyone has dealt with a problem like this, and if so, what worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: This answer deals with type `T` (known at the compilation stage) unlike `Any` in your `convert`. Otherwise you would have to use reflection in order to call appropriate constructor and it wouldn't return you an actual type. Using Java reflection it's something like (pseudo-code):

```
 def convert(x: Any): MyType = {
   val clazz = x.getClass.getName
   val caseClassCompanionName = ... 
   Class.forName(caseClassCompanionName).getMethod("apply").invoke(null, x).asInstanceOf[MyType] 
 }
```

or you can use `ClassTag`/`TypeTag` from Scala-reflection or write a macro that will generate appropriate `convert()` code for you.

Anyways, reflection-based approach doesn't bring much type-safety (and might easily break after Scala updates), so my answer is intended to show how to wrap a known type without using pattern-matching:

> I need to map values of some type T to MyType.

---

Yes you can use implicit classes in many ways, one approach:

```
trait MyType //represents your union (sum) of types

case class StringValue(s: String) extends MyType
implicit class ToStringValue(s: String){
   def toMyType = StringValue(s)
}

case class IntValue(i: Int) extends MyType
implicit class ToIntValue(i: Int){
   def toMyType = IntValue(i)
}

scala> "aaa".toMyType
res0: StringValue = StringValue(aaa)

scala> 1.toMyType
res1: IntValue = IntValue(1)
```

You could notice that it requires even more code than pattern matching, BUT it returns you an actual type instead general `MyType` unlike your convert.

Shorter way to do that is overloading:

```
object Converter{
   def toMyType(s: String) = StringValue(s)
   def toMyType(i: Int) = IntValue(i)
}
scala> Converter.toMyType("aaa")
res2: StringValue = StringValue(aaa)

scala> Converter.toMyType(1)
res3: IntValue = IntValue(1)
```

If you just wanna wrap any possible type, the easiest way is

```
case class MyValue[T](value: T) //represents your union (sum) of types
```

Then you can define type-specific operations over your MyValue in a type-class style

```
implicit class RichMyInt(myValue: MyValue[Int]){
  def inc = myValue.copy(value = myValue.value + 1)
}

implicit class RichMyString(myValue: MyValue[String]){
  def inc = myValue.copy(value = myValue.value + " ")
}

scala> MyValue(5).inc
res4: MyValue[Int] = MyValue(6)

scala> MyValue("5").inc
res5: MyValue[String] = MyValue(5 )

scala> MyValue(1.0).inc
<console>:18: error: value inc is not a member of MyValue[Double]
   MyValue(1.0).inc
                ^
scala> MyValue(1.0) //unlike previous solutions, it allows any type to be wrapped
res7: MyValue[Double] = MyValue(1.0)
```

---

P.S. You can restrict types for `MyValue[T]` constructor using overloading (or even evidences):

```
trait MyValue[T]{
  def value: T
}
object Factory{
  private case class MyValueImpl[T] (value: T) extends MyValue[T]
  def create(t: String): MyValue[String] = MyValueImpl(t)
  def create(t: Int): MyValue[Int] = MyValueImpl(t)
}

scala> Factory.create(1)
res1: MyValue[Int] = MyValueImpl(1)

scala> Factory.create("a")
res2: MyValue[String] = MyValueImpl(a)

scala> Factory.create(1.0)
<console>:13: error: overloaded method value create with alternatives:
  (t: Int)MyValue[Int] <and>
  (t: String)MyValue[String]
 cannot be applied to (Double)
       Factory.create(1.0)
               ^
```

You could also try private constructor's , like `class MyValue[T] private(value: T)` (instead of `private case class`) but for case classes `apply` escapes that restriction (at least in my REPL)

Of course you can do `case class MyValue[T <: AnyVal](value: T)` if you just want a wrapper around atomic types. You can even increase performance of your wrapper by doing `case class MyValue[T](value: T) extends AnyVal` which produces a [value class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html), so no addtional reference is created when you do `MyValue(1)` - in byte-code it's just going to be the same `Int`.

Comment: Awesome, thorough answer! Thank you :)